# Direct sum of commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a direct sum of ideals
$R=R_1\oplus R_2\oplus\dots\oplus R_k$. Each ideal $R_i$ is commutative of order $p_{i}^{n_{i}}$ ($p$ is prime), and has a unity. How to show that the direct sum of these ideals is commutative?

Comment: Multiplication is defined term-wise, so commutativity follows trivially from the commutativity of each component.

Comment: @YACP Let $R=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$; the summands are ideals which have their unity (different from the unity in $R$, of course).

Answer (score 1):

It's sufficient to prove the statement for $R=I\oplus J$, because the general one follows by induction.

The conditions on the ideals $I$ and $J$ are that $I+J=R$ and $I\cap J=\{0\}$; since $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$ for any ideals $I$ and $J$, we can say that
$$
xy=0,\text{ for $x\in I$, $y\in J$}.
$$

Therefore, if $a,b\in R$, we can write
$$
a=x_1+y_1,\quad b=x_2+y_2,\quad(x_1,x_2\in I, y_1,y_2\in J)
$$
and so
\begin{align}
ab&=(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)=x_1x_2+y_1y_2.\\
ba&=(x_2+y_2)(x_1+y_1)=x_2x_1+y_2y_1.
\end{align}
Now, commutativity of $I$ and $J$ ends the proof.